# Server side processing after callback from external login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-identity

I have 3rd party login enabled in my project that is using ASP.Net Identity. After the initial post request I redirect through the 3rd party login, and return to OnGetCallbackAsync.  However I want to create an account with the usermanager and redirect to some other page.

```
public IActionResult OnPost ( string provider, string returnUrl = null )
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Page( "./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl } );
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties( provider, redirectUrl );
    return new ChallengeResult( provider, properties );
}

public IActionResult OnGetAsync ()
{
    return RedirectToPage( "./Login" );
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync ( string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null )
{
    ...
   return Page()
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync ( string returnUrl = null )
{
   ... //create accounts etc.
   return LocalRedirect( returnUrl );
}
```

When it return from the 3rd party provider it hits my OnGetCallbackAsync method.  Does some logic then shows a page where the user inputs their email and a submit button.  When they submit it hits the post confirmation method, and creates a user based on the input email, and the 3rd party info.

My issue is I want to skip this step of the user inputting any information or having to click another submit button.

**Should I be worried about keeping that get request idempotent? If yes how should I go about hitting that post request or doing the server side processing I need to do?**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automatically redirect, 
You can just call **OnPostConfirmationAsync** from **OnGetCallbackAsync**. something like this

```
public IActionResult OnPost ( string provider, string returnUrl = null )
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Page( "./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl } );
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties( provider, redirectUrl );
    return new ChallengeResult( provider, properties );
}

public IActionResult OnGetAsync ()
{
    return RedirectToPage( "./Login" );
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync ( string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null )
{
    ...
   return await OnPostConfirmationAsync(returnUrl);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync ( string returnUrl = null )
{
   ... //create accounts etc.
   return LocalRedirect( returnUrl );
}
```